# Location icon appears every time I launch my app

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I have a problem with my app - every time when I launch my app location icon in statusbar appears, even if I don't use location.

My code:

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
         [[LocationManager manager] startLocation];
         return YES;
    }
```

LocationManager.m

```
@implementation LocationManager

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

+ (instancetype)manager {
    static LocationManager *instance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [[LocationManager alloc] init];
    });
    return instance;
}

- (void)startLocation {
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

#pragma mark - CLLocatiomManager Delegate
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
...
}
```

After I allow location services to use my location, location indicator appears every time when I launch my app (even if I remove this line from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method).
But if I remove this line on first launch (installing app) location indicator doesn't appear, so it is only one line where I use location services.

I want when the line is commented then location indicator doesn't appear.

Comment: @franiis I mean, if I comment this line, the indicator still appears

Comment: And what capabilities are you requesting in `info.plist`?

Comment: @franiis Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description, Privacy - Location Always Usage Description, Privacy - Location Usage Description, Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description. I wrote there all, Is this a problem? I'll try to remove the extra ones

Comment: @franiis I left only the "Privacy-Location When In Use Usage Description", but the problem still exists

Answer (score 0):

Base on your Singleton class.

Locationmanager will start location while calling

```
[[LocationManager manager] startLocation];
```

So, that only location icon was showing on status bar.
Better you can call a startLocation when you need a location.

After fetching location have to call

```
[self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: But even if I comment this line [[LocationManager manager] startLocation]; after first launch, the indicator still appears and disappears after 5 seconds

Comment: Yes, Your location service was called already. So, Have to stopUpdatingLocation while your app goes background or terminated state. OS will disappear location icon after few seconds

Answer (score -1):

I realized that it was because of OneSignal.
The decision is:

```
[OneSignal setLocationShared:NO];
```

Comment: Okay, but you never mentioned OneSignal in the question, so the question as posed was unanswerable.